# Why SELECT 0, ... instead of SELECT

Tags: sql, sqlite, core-data

Lets say I have a SQLite database that contains a table:

```
sqlite> create table person (id integer, firstname varchar, lastname varchar);
```

Now I want to get every entry which is in the table.

```
sqlite> select t0.id, t0.firstname, t0.lastname from person t0;
```

This works fine and this it what I would use. However I have worked with a framework from Apple (Core Data) that generates SQL. This framework generates a slightly different SQL query:

```
sqlite> select 0, t0.id, t0.firstname, t0.lastname from person t0;
```

Every SQL query generated by this framework begins with "select 0,". Why is that?

I tried to use the explain command to see whats going on but this was inconclusive - at least to me.

```
sqlite> explain select t0.id, t0.firstname, t0.lastname from person t0;
addr        opcode      p1          p2          p3          p4          p5          comment   
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           Trace       0           0           0                       00          NULL      
1           Goto        0           11          0                       00          NULL      
2           OpenRead    0           2           0           3           00          NULL      
3           Rewind      0           9           0                       00          NULL      
4           Column      0           0           1                       00          NULL      
5           Column      0           1           2                       00          NULL      
6           Column      0           2           3                       00          NULL      
7           ResultRow   1           3           0                       00          NULL      
8           Next        0           4           0                       01          NULL      
9           Close       0           0           0                       00          NULL      
10          Halt        0           0           0                       00          NULL      
11          Transactio  0           0           0                       00          NULL      
12          VerifyCook  0           1           0                       00          NULL      
13          TableLock   0           2           0           person      00          NULL      
14          Goto        0           2           0                       00          NULL
```

And the table for the second query looks like this:

```
sqlite> explain select 0, t0.id, t0.firstname, t0.lastname from person t0;
addr        opcode      p1          p2          p3          p4          p5          comment   
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           Trace       0           0           0                       00          NULL      
1           Goto        0           12          0                       00          NULL      
2           OpenRead    0           2           0           3           00          NULL      
3           Rewind      0           10          0                       00          NULL      
4           Integer     0           1           0                       00          NULL      
5           Column      0           0           2                       00          NULL      
6           Column      0           1           3                       00          NULL      
7           Column      0           2           4                       00          NULL      
8           ResultRow   1           4           0                       00          NULL      
9           Next        0           4           0                       01          NULL      
10          Close       0           0           0                       00          NULL      
11          Halt        0           0           0                       00          NULL      
12          Transactio  0           0           0                       00          NULL      
13          VerifyCook  0           1           0                       00          NULL      
14          TableLock   0           2           0           person      00          NULL      
15          Goto        0           2           0                       00          NULL
```

Answer (score 17):

Some frameworks do this in order to tell, without any doubt, whether a row from that table was returned.

Consider

```
  A      B
+---+  +---+------+
| a |  | a | b    |
+---+  +---+------+
| 0 |  | 0 |    1 |
+---+  +---+------+
| 1 |  | 1 | NULL |
+---+  +---+------+
| 2 |
+---+

SELECT A.a, B.b
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON B.a = A.a

  Results
+---+------+
| a | b    |
+---+------+
| 0 |    1 |
+---+------+
| 1 | NULL |
+---+------+
| 2 | NULL |
+---+------+
```

In this result set, it is not possible to see that `a = 1` exists in table B, but `a = 2` does not. To get that information, you need to select a non-nullable expression from table b, and the simplest way to do that is to select a simple constant value.

```
SELECT A.a, B.x, B.b
FROM A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 0 AS x, B.a, B.b FROM B) AS B
ON B.a = A.a

  Results
+---+------+------+
| a | x    | b    |
+---+------+------+
| 0 |    0 |    1 |
+---+------+------+
| 1 |    0 | NULL |
+---+------+------+
| 2 | NULL | NULL |
+---+------+------+
```

There are a lot of situations where these constant values are not strictly required, for example when you have no joins, or when you could choose a non-nullable column from b instead, but they don't cause any harm either, so they can just be included unconditionally.

Comment: But the constant `0` is *not* from table B; it is unconditionally returned in every result record.

Comment: But Core Data puts the `0` into the outermost query.

Comment: @CL. Indeed, but why bother with a special exception to not include it in the outermost query, if the query performs equally correct and fast if the constant is left in? (To be perfectly clear, I'm not saying for sure this is why the constant is included, only that this is why some other frameworks do it, and it could very well be why it happens here too.)

Answer (score 9):

When I have code to dynamically generate a `WHERE` clause, I usually start the clause with a:

```
WHERE 1 = 1
```

Then the loop to add additional conditions always adds each condition in the same format:

```
AND x = y
```

without having to put conditional logic in place to check if this is the first condition or not: "if this is the first condition then start with the `WHERE` keyword, else add the `AND` keyword.

So I can imagine a framework doing this for similar reasons. If you start the statement with a `SELECT 0` then the code to add subsequent columns can be in a loop without any conditional statements. Just add `, colx` each time without any conditional checking along the lines of "if this is the first column, don't put a comma before the column name, otherwise do".

Example pseudo code:

```
String query = "SELECT 0";

for (Column col in columnList)
    query += ", col";
```

Comment: I see your point but then again: In Objective-C you could simply join your column names like this: 

    [@[@"firstName", @"lastName"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];

So no if needed here.

Comment: That would be exactly the kind of code I would look to avoid :)

Comment: I would much rather use componentsJoinedByString instead of a for loop. Maybe its just a matter of taste... :)

Comment: @cmk: Or a matter of a different consideration, like e.g. performance. I don't know Objective-C but the code example in your other comment seems to me a syntactic sugar of some kind, i.e. something designed for the convenience of the programmer rather than for efficiency. A plain and simple `for` loop without conditional might compile in a much more efficient piece of code than that `componentsJoinedByString` thing, whatever it may be. Don't get me wrong, I've got nothing against syntactic sugar in general, but we are talking about a *framework*, where efficiency should be key (or partly key).

Comment: componentsJoinedByString is simply doing a for-loop internally so it should be as fast as your code but then again: You have a little less flexibility when using componentsJoinedByString... We have implemented our own ORM framework and used componentsJoinedByString heavily without any problems regarding performance. The bottle necks are typically somewhere else - at least in our case. But thanks for the input - I really appreciate it.

Comment: Both this and @hvd's answer make sense. Up-voting both.

Answer (score 0):

Only Apple knows … but I see two possibilities:

1. Inserting a dummy column ensures that the *actual* output columns are numbered beginning with 1, not 0. If some existing interface already assumed one-based numbering, doing it this way in the SQL backend might have been the easiest solution.
2. If you make a query for multiple objects using multiple subqueries, a value like this could be used to determine from which subquery a record originates:

   ```
   SELECT 0, t0.firstname, ... FROM PERSON t0 WHERE t0.id = 123
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1, t0.firstname, ... FROM PERSON t0 WHERE t0.id = 456
   ```

   (I don't know if Core Data actually does this.)

---

Your `EXPLAIN` output shows that the only difference is (at address 4) that the second program sets the extra column to zero, so there is only a minimal performance difference.